# Opencv java match finder

Tags: java, opencv, matching, orb

I would like to know how to find match distances but after a while MatOfDMatch matches gets no matches. Im detecting faces by Haar detector and next thing i do here is matching one of the new detections to template images and if distance is low enough it will attach new image of detection. Problem is matchlist is empty after a couple of iteratons.

```
@Override
public void match(List<Template> listOfTemplates, List<Template> listOfDetections) {
    FeatureDetector Fdetector = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.ORB);
    DescriptorExtractor Fdescriptor = DescriptorExtractor.create(DescriptorExtractor.ORB);
    DescriptorMatcher matcher = DescriptorMatcher.create(DescriptorMatcher.BRUTEFORCE);
    for (Template template : listOfTemplates) {


        MatOfKeyPoint templateKeyPoints=new MatOfKeyPoint();
        Mat templateDescriptors=new Mat();
        Fdetector.detect(template.image, templateKeyPoints);
        Fdescriptor.compute(template.image, templateKeyPoints, templateDescriptors);

        for (Template detection : listOfDetections) {
            MatOfKeyPoint detectionKeyPoints=new MatOfKeyPoint();
            Mat detectionDescriptors=new Mat(); 

            Fdetector.detect(detection.image, detectionKeyPoints);
            Fdescriptor.compute(detection.image, detectionKeyPoints, detectionDescriptors);
            MatOfDMatch matches=new MatOfDMatch();
            if (detectionDescriptors.cols() <= templateDescriptors.cols()) {
                matcher.match(detectionDescriptors,templateDescriptors , matches);
            } else {
                matcher.match(templateDescriptors, detectionDescriptors, matches);
            }
            List<DMatch> matchlist=matches.toList();
            for (DMatch dMatch : matchlist) {
                if (dMatch.distance<80) {
                        template.IdOfContourMatcher =listOfDetections.indexOf(detection);   
                }
                    System.out.println(dMatch.distance);
            }



        }


    }

}
```

}